# web.config for particular domain

Tags: web-config, iis-7.5, custom-errors

I have two domain names: `www.website.com` and `www.website.cc`. Both domain names direct to the same IIS 7.5 website. My `web.config` has `customErrors` section. I want to set different `customErrors` urls for `.com` and `.cc`. Is it possible to create a subsection in `web.config` for `.cc` domain?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have different `customErrors` Elements in your `web.config`.

You probably might use the `defaultRedirect` Attribute to point to a generic Error Handling Page. From there you should be able to handle the different sites and redirect from there on...

You might also consider to use the different ASP.NET Events at Page (`Page_Error`) and Application level (Global.asax -> `Application_Error`).